# Creating a normal distribution with rejection method yields wrong prefactor

Tags: fortran, normal-distribution

I'm trying to create normal distribution out of evenly distributed values in Fortran with the rejection method. It actually works more or less well, but I don't get exactly the result that I want.

I generate the normal distribution with this segment of code

```
    function generator result(c)
            implicit none
            integer, dimension(2) :: clock
            double precision :: c,d
            call System_clock(count=clock(1))
            call random_seed(put=clock)
            !initialize matrix with random values
            call random_number(c)
    end function

    subroutine Rejection(aa,bb,NumOfPoints)
            implicit none
            double precision :: xx, yy, cc
            integer :: ii, jj, kk
            integer, intent(in) :: NumOfPoints
            double precision, intent(in) :: aa, bb
            cc=1
            xx=generator()
            allocate(rejectionArray(NumOfPoints))
            do ii=1, NumOfPoints

            call random_number(xx)
            xx=aa+(bb-aa)*xx
            call random_number(yy)
                    do while(cc*yy>1/sqrt(pi)*exp(-xx**2))
                            call random_number(xx)
                            xx=aa+xx*(bb-aa)
                            call random_number(yy)
                    end do
                    rejectionArray(ii)=xx
            end do
    end subroutine
```

Since I am using as function 1/pi *exp(-x^2), I thought that the normal distribution that I obtain should also give a distribution with the prefactor 1/pi^(1/2), but it does not. If I create a histogram and fit this histogram with a normal distribution, I obtain as prefactor approximately 0.11.

How is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is how I create the histogram

```
    implicit none
    double precision ::  aa, bb
    integer :: NumOfPoints, ii, kk, NumOfBoxes, counter, CounterTotal,counterTotal2
    logical :: exists
    character(len=15) :: frmat
    double precision :: Intermediate
    %read NumOfPoints (Total amount of random numbers), NumOfBoxes
    %(TotalAmountofBins)
    open(unit=39, action='read', status='old', name='samples.txt')
            read(39,*) NumOfPoints, aa, bb, NumOfBoxes
    close(39)
    % number of Counts will be stored temporarily in 'counter'
    counter=0
    open(unit=39, action='write', status='replace', name='distRejection.txt')
    Call Rejection(aa,bb,NumOfPoints)

    do ii=1, NumOfBoxes
            counter=0
            %calculate the middle of the bin
            Intermediate=aa+(2*ii-1)*((bb-aa)/NumOfBoxes)/2
             %go through all the random numbers and check if they are within
             % one of the bins. If they are in one bin -->increase Counter
             % by one
            do kk=1, size(rejectionArray,1)
                    if(abs(RejectionArray(kk)-intermediate).le.((bb-aa)/NumOfBoxes/2)) then
                            counter=counter+1
                   end if
            end do
            %save Points + relative number of Counts in file
            write(39,100)intermediate,dble( counter)/dble(NumOfPoints)
            100 format (f10.3,T20,f10.3,/)

    end do
    close(39)
```

This is what I obtain as histogram: [image]

The prefactor now is 0.056 what is 1/sqrt(pi)*1/10. This is 1/10 times my desired prefactor. The Problem is that this prefactor does not get any better if I enlarge the Region over which I integrate the function. This means that if create with this Code a Distribution from -5000 to + 5000 then I still obtain the same prefactor even though the integral from -5000 to 5000 of this function leads to 0.2 with the Distribution that I used. (I took the randomly distributed values and put them into matlab and calculated the numerical integral from -5000 to 5000 with those values and obtained 0.2. This means that here the prefactor of the integral should be 1/pi*1/5. Besieds that, I am puzzled by the fact that the Integral from -5000 to +50000 of a gaussian is only 0.2. According to mathematica this integral is approximately 1. So something has got to be wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used your routine to generate 1000 points between -2 and 2 and obtained a gaussian distribution.

How do you generate your histogram? The un-normalized histogram can be plotted with the function `N exp(-x**2)/sqrt(pi) * dx` where N is the number of points and dx is the binning interval.

Comment: The Problem is not that I do not obtain a gausssian Distribution. The Distribution that I obtain is a more or less perfect gaussian Distribution. The Problem is when I fit the Distribution with gnuplot, the Fitting Parameters are wrong. I should obtain as prefactor 1/pi which is more or less 0.56, but I obtain 0.11 instead

Comment: Since you asked: I create the histogram myself. I wrote a function that Counts all the data Points within some bins and then I plot this with gnuplot

Comment: The result cannot be a perfect gaussian distribution for several reasons. (i) using a finite number of counts will result in "noise" in the distribution. (ii) the finite range implies that the distribution is not normalized over -infinity,+infinity but aa,bb. If you have already taken that into account, the full Fortran and gnuplot code can help to investigate the problem.

Comment: I do not expect it to be a perfect gaussian Distribution, but if I take more than 500 000 different values and the range from -500 to + 500, I would expect it to be much better than it actually is

Comment: @user9996 Does your histogram data contain raw counts of samples for each bin? Or are they already normalized in some way? (Btw, the interval can be [-5, 5] etc.)

Comment: I divide the number of Counts in each bin by the total amount of data Points. So they are normalized.I added the Code + one of the histograms that I created with the Code in the entry post. I hope everything should be clear.

Comment: Can you try plotting dble( counter ) / dble( NumOfPoints ) / dx, where dx = ( bb - aa ) / NumOfBoxes? (i.e., we divide further by the bin width to normalize the histogram.)

Comment: I don't get why this should work, but it produces perfect results :) Thanks a lot! I still have to figure out, why this works.

Comment: The number of counts for probability P(x) is counts(bin x) = P(x)*dx*N_counts. So to go from "counts" to "P" you do P(x) = counts(x)/dx/N_counts. This is the plotting formula I gave in my reply :-)

Comment: correct! I just was a Little confused! Thanks a lot.